Sol got stuck on associated account
TL;DR
This account https://solscan.io/account/C4CBuAwkP1MJrJh5umKigUtx7EtTGaqHqVYFVUQ2HDtr this account was created by my wallet 6UV7BoMkyjt2aWTaZJnqbhDZWynFmmfBwqNPjKvQ72c8. So my wallet is Authority.
Sols got stuck there. How I can get them?
More context
I played with swap-instructions of jupiter API. There were several transactions per swap. One time I made such transaction it was interrupted and I noticed that Sol got stuck on that wallet.
P.S. If you get here with similar issue - check my answer below. Might help you :)

As previously answer here - How do I transfer the SOL on my token account?, you need to move the tokens inside your ATA to another address and then close that ATA to recover the SOL.

Hey! Thanks for your reply. I've added P.S. section with transfer results. It doesn't work ;/

So, for whoever meet such an issue - the solution is to repeat any 2 transactions with account opening and account closing (amount of sol does not matter)
In my case I executed those 2 transactions and sol was back to my wallet
https://solscan.io/tx/3DALC5LTLVzJkBHR3U2kF1S3LszcUXxxCcyVb6sqF7wafYRDULhGpAej6eCDzvaK6U6Ubrir3G8c5QU69V9uebvv
https://solscan.io/tx/88xBczU7aELyu4uxRYAdsvy9WAUTGsLZzanJ6Uj1kgZriBuJbhckMyYUQG6YNYjw6surDFutfSK12HhAgAaHY1x
